# Google Calendar API with React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-calendar-api, google-api-js-client

I'm trying to use Google Calendar API in a React and Firebase app. I'm authenticating to Google in my `App.js` component, while I attempt to access the Google Calendar API in my `Calendar.js` component.

Here's my `App.js`:

```
import React from 'react'
import firebase from 'firebase'
import './App.css'
import AppBody from '../AppBody'
import AppHeader from '../AppHeader'


class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      user: null,
      googleAuth: null
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    // capture authentication callback
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user !== this.state.user) {
        this.setState({user})
      }
    })

    const script = document.createElement('script')
    script.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/api.js'

    script.onload = () => {
      window.gapi.load('client:auth2', () => {
        window.gapi.client.init({
          clientId: 'client_Id',
          scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'
        }).then(() =>
          this.setState({googleAuth: window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()})
        )
      })
    }

    document.head.appendChild(script)
  }

  handleAuthClick = () => {

    let {googleAuth} = this.state

    if (this.state.user) {

      googleAuth.signOut().then(firebase.auth().signOut())

    } else {

      googleAuth.signIn().then(googleUser => {

          var unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {
            unsubscribe()

            if (!isUserEqual(googleUser, firebaseUser)) {

              var credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token)
              firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential)
                .then(user => this.setState({user}))
                .catch(error => console.error(error))

            } else {

              console.log('User already signed-in Firebase.')
              console.log(googleUser)
            }
          })
      })

      let isUserEqual = (googleUser, firebaseUser) => {
        if (firebaseUser) {
          var providerData = firebaseUser.providerData
          for (let i = 0; i < providerData.length; i++) {
            if (providerData[i].providerId === firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID &&
                providerData[i].uid === googleUser.getBasicProfile().getId()) {
              return true
            }
          }
        }
        return false
      }
    }
  }

  render() {

    let {user} = this.state

    return (
      <div>
        <AppHeader onAuthClick={this.handleAuthClick} user={user} />
        {user ? <AppBody userID={user.uid} /> : undefined}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

And here is my `Calendar.js` (it's loaded by the AppBody component)

```
import React from 'react'
import './Calendar.css'


class Calendar extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      events: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    if (window.gapi && window.gapi.client) {

      var timeMin = new Date()
      timeMin.setHours(0, 0, 0)

      var timeMax = new Date()
      timeMax.setHours(23, 59, 59)

      window.gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', () => {
        window.gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
          'calendarId': 'primary',
          'timeMin': timeMin.toISOString(),
          'timeMax': timeMax.toISOString(),
          'singleEvents': true
        }).then(response => {
          let events = []
          response.result.items.forEach(event => {
            events.push({
              title: event.summary,
              start: new Date(event.start.dateTime),
              end: new Date(event.end.dateTime)
            })
          })
          this.setState({events})
        })
      })
    }
  }

  render() {

    console.log(this.state.events)

    return (
      ...render events...
    )
  }
}

export default Calendar
```

The problem is, if I keep refreshing the screen, I get very inconsistent results:

- Sometimes I get and render the list of events.
- More often than not, I get no events.
- On occasion, I get the following error:

`Uncaught {result: {…}, body: "{↵ "error": {↵  "errors": [↵   {↵    "domain": "us…e Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."↵ }↵}↵", headers: {…}, status: 403, statusText: null}`

I'm obviously not using the Calendar API correctly. What am I doing wrong though?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that window.gapi is the Calendar API object that you're setting via a script tag and calling off of the window object, please consider whether the script has loaded by the time you're calling it in your componentDidMount.

In the case that the script races ahead of your component mounting, you'll have events rendered.
In the case that the script hasn't loaded when your component is mounting, your state.events array will be empty, resulting in no events. 
The last error appears to be a quota error; you can check your api settings here: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/calendar-json.googleapis.com/overview

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not worried about window.gapi, because once it loads in App.js, it forces the Calendar to reload by setting the user state object. As for the error though, it says "Continued use requires signup", which I suspect is because I call the API as an anonymous user, although I would expect to be doing that as a logged in user (see App.js). This is the part I am confused about.

Comment: Are you providing an API key and the client_ID? I don't see an API key in your gapi.client.init call. Your code has the string 'client_Id' but that could be just for masking purposes. See here for more detail on gapi.client.init: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#gapiclientinitargs

Comment: Yes, I am providing the client ID. I have tried adding the API key, although I haven't observed any differences in described behaviour.